# How to call server node using ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

```
var express = require('express'); var app = express(); app.get('/',function(req, res) {  res.send('Hello World!');}); app.listen(3000, function () {  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'); });
```

How to call server node using ionic?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you make an `http` call in ionic component.

```
export class HomePage {

  posts: any;

  constructor(public http: Http) {

    this.http.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/new/.json?limit=10').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        this.posts = data.data.children;
    });

  }
}
```

Check [this](http://www.gajotres.net/ionic-2-making-rest-http-requests-like-a-pro/) out for more understanding.